# UnicodeDecodeError - unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3

Tags: python, pip

Olá! 
Estou tendo problemas para instalar o `pip` (gerenciador de pacotes `python`). A instalação deveria ocorrer ao mesmo tempo em que é feita a instalação do python (usei: `brew install python` => instala a `versão 2.7.10`, sistema `Mac OS`).

Na primeira tentativa funcionou! Porém necessitei retirar o `pip`. 
Estou tentando criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento `python` independente do sistema, ou seja, todos os executáveis ficam em

> /usr/local/bin

através do gerenciador `HOMEBREW`. Assim os pacotes do `pip` estariam em

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Já tentei instalar pelo `easy_install` e pelo código fonte do projeto, mas sem êxito.
Mensagem de erro:

> unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como solucionar isso?

Comment: Essa é a última linha da mensagem de erro, certo? Tem como postar a saída do easy_install inteira?

Comment: O seu nome de usuário é o seu nome, algo tipo `Alã` ou `Alã Damasceno` ou algo que tenha `ã` no meio?