# Problemas com a instalação do pip (gerenciador de pacotes python)

Tags: python-2.7, osx, pip, homebrew

Utilizo o Mac OS e uso o `HomeBrew` como gerenciador de pacotes.
Instalei o `python 2.7.10`. Juntamente com está instalação era para ter ocorrido a do `pip`. Contudo o seguinte problema ocorre:

```
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child raise child_exception
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Parece que o problema está com a codificação. Fiz uma tentativa de editar o arquivo `subprocess.py`colocando `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, mas sem êxito.
Percebi também que o problema não é com o gerenciador `brew`, pois o mesmo aconteceu com o `easy_install`:
 File

```
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Queria utilizar o `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-package/` como diretório para os pacotes python2.7

Comment: Possível duplicata de: ["UnicodeDecodeError - unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67764/215)

Comment: Como resolver isso @mgibsonbr?  Tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Infelizmente, não. Já tinha visto a pergunta anterior, mas como não tenho experiência com o Mac OS ou com o HomeBrew não tenho ideia do que possa ser. Nunca tive esse problema no Windows nem no Linux (os que eu já usei o `pip`).

Comment: Este problema não ocorria, mas quando desinstalei o pip, porque acreditava que tinha problemas com ele, não mais consegui instalar.

Comment: Esse erro ocorre quando você tenta instalar *o próprio Python*, ou é ao instalar alguma biblioteca ou pacote em particular? Pelo que venho lendo por aí, esse erro é comum quando se tenta codificar ou decodificar uma string duas vezes (i.e. de string pra byte e de novo pra byte, ou de byte pra string e de novo pra string). Pode ocorrer por um erro de programação, mas não consigo imaginar isso acontecendo dentro do próprio Python... Talvez tenha ocorrido alguma mistura de código do Python 2 e do 3, não sei...

Comment: O erro ocorre na instalação do python através do: `brew install python` e através do `easy_install pip` @mgibsonbr.

Comment: É, acho que só alguém com experiência com Python no Mac poderá te ajudar, eu estou totalmente no escuro... :(

Comment: Não acredito que tenha ocorrido mistura de código. O `pip3` funciona muito bem. Ele foi instalando junto com o `python3` atráves do brew. Contudo, como você bem sabe, existem projetos que só rodam em _python 2x_

Comment: Foram 3 tentativas: **1-** usando o `brew` durante a instalação do `python`. **2-** usando o `easy_install`, nativo do sistema. **3-** baixando o projeto pip do _github_ executando o `python setup.py install`. O problema sempre é o mesmo, acusando em diretórios distintos. No primeiro e terceiro aponta para o `/usr/local/...` e no segundo para `/System/Libary/...`

Comment: os problemas parecem estar associados ao `subprocess.py`

Comment: O `raise child_exception` me dá a impressão de que o subprocess.py está só relançando uma exceção que foi gerada em outro lugar. Isso indicaria que a culpa não precisa ser exatamente do subprocess.py (e da codificação desse arquivo). Você pode experimentar por uns prints nessa região do código pra ver o que está acontecendo. Outra possibilidade é usar o `strace` (se tiver isso no OSX) para descobrir quais arquivos o subprocess.py estava tentando ler antes de ocorrer o seu erro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tentei o Ananconda, Homebrew e estes apenas bagunçaram meu sistema de pastas. Eu gosto de controlar onde estão os meus arquivos e recomendo uma receita bem mais prática e leve que aprendi no MIT.

Eu uso um Mac Book, e depois de muitas tentativas e erros, descobri que se deve evitar ao máximo as versões mais recentes de OS. Então fiz um downgrade total do meu mac (configuração de fábrica) do Yosemite para o Montain Lion. Esta é a melhor forma de colocar todos os arquivos no lugar e solucionar erros crônicos. Custa quase um dia, mas depois se ganham outros.

Este seria o primeiro passo desta "receita", mas é opcional dependendo do caso. No meu, não conseguia plotar nenhum gráfico pois anaconda e homebrew criam suas pastas e ambientes, ao que parece, haviam diferentes ambientes sudo e não-sudo que eu levaria mais tempo e seria mais chato do que reinstalar tudo.

Mas para uma primeira experiência dessa receita tente:

1 -  No terminal digite: Python
   Confirme: Python 2.7.2

2 - Escreva no terminal `quit()` para sair do Python

3 - Agora digite no terminal: `idle &`
   Isso gera uma janela IDLE Shell do Python fora do terminal e deixa o terminal e o python independentes.

4 - Nas opções do Python, do menu principal, você pode configurar em General como abrir o IDLE em Start Up, selecionado Open Text Edit. Assim, ao digitar `idle &` você abrirá direto o programa de edição para ler ou escrever seu código antes de rodá-lo. O shell você pode abrir do menu deste editor diretamente.

5 - Agora, antes do passo 6, verifique se o de fato o Python não está ativado no terminal digitando `quit()`

6 - No terminal escreva `easy_install pip` (easy_install é um instalador de comando do mac)

7 - E depois de confirmada a instalação com sucesso do pip, escreva no terminal `sudo pip install pylab`
pylab é o pacote científico do python que os estudantes do MIT utilizam, ele inclui matlibplot, netoworkx, numPy, etc.

8 - O resto você já sabe. No Python, use  `import pylab` para usar este recurso.